# How can I use the new Spotify API using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, spotify

I'm trying to get some data from Spotify, since they recently changed their API I wrote a new function that follows new directives:

```
function get_Spotify() {
    $getTrackID = $this->db->query("SELECT `trackid` FROM `spotify` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $TrackID = $getTrackID->fetch_assoc();
    $id=$TrackID['trackid'];

    $client_id = '********************'; 
    $client_secret = '**********************'; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     'grant_type=client_credentials' ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($client_id.':'.$client_secret))); 
    $result=curl_exec($ch); 
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    curl_close($ch);    

    //find spotify data
    $spotifyURL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/'.$id;
    $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$result["access_token"];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $spotifyURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
    curl_close($ch);

    $spotifyURL_artist = $json['artists'][0]['href'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $spotifyURL_artist);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $json_artist = curl_exec($ch);
    $data_artist = json_decode($json_artist, true);
    curl_close($ch);

    $Spotify_Player = '
    <div class="container-playerspot">
        <div class="playerspot">
            <div class="bg_spotify" style="background:url('.$data_artist['images'][0]['url'].');"><div class="ert-spotify"></div></div>
            <ul class="player_spot-info info-one">
                <li>'.$json['artists'][0]['name'].'</li>
                <li>'.$json['name'].'</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="player_spot-info info-two">
                <li>'.$json['artists'][0]['name'].'</li>
                <li>'.$json['name'].'</li>
                <li><span id="duration"></span><i> / </i>0.30</li>
            </ul>
            <audio id="audio-player_spot" ontimeupdate="SeekBar()" ondurationchange="CreateSeekBar()" preload="none" loop>
            <source src="'.$json['preview_url'].'" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>';

    return $Spotify_Player;

}
```

But my page load slow so after investigating using `microtime()` I found that this function (`get_Spotify()`) takes about **300 Milliseconds**.

**Is there anything wrong with my code that can lead to such a disastrous result?**

P.S.

MySQL table actually has only 4 results, so I exclude my query from possible reason.

Comment: I have just read your code fast, but are you curling three times? I use curl to download HTML files on my page and they are about 1 second each (not tested with microtime, just counted in head).

Comment: How can I grant client credentials otherwise? I'm not so good with cURL

Comment: disastrous compared to what ? 300 ms for 3 https calls over the ever-so-impredictable internet seems more than 'fair'. Surely you are gaging 'goodness' against a yardstick we cant see in your post.

Comment: My point was three curls and 300 ms is not bad. I don't know anything about the API so I don't know if there is any other way. But if what you need to do takes 300 ms then you can't expect it to be faster. The curls takes time. But you could microtime it further and see if it's one specific curl that takes time. You may be able to cache data?

Comment: @Andreas Ok thanks, I thought there was a better way to do this.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg you're right but I was referring to good page load time (below 200 milliseconds).

Comment: Maybe there is. I'm just saying 300 for what it does is not bad. But maybe caching data is an option? If every other curl is about the same say 10 songs then caching those 10 songs information could help a lot.

Comment: @Andreas yes of course I already use cache

Comment: 300ms seems fair with so many calls. As @Andreas said, you could cache the results on server side (php), and only curl if the cached result is too old. Another solution would be using ajax on frontend: curl requests would be done asynchronously after the page has loaded.