# Is there anything wrong with my request when CURL POST request returns error 55

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a POST request using curl in php and am getting curl error #55. Have been looking around and don't see much information on this error. I don't think my request is formed wrong.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$encoded = base64_encode("12345:12345");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
    "Accept: application/json",
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $encoded,
    "Accept: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
   "grant_type" => "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token" => 'CxRmNSepUaA41Zs8xIN68fC2wYbRrsrQWKE9547fF6Q12LDOpr551xb95K62+EqnGq6glEHXF4R3qgtgCnOVpr9wFAaxta5/iBKzYBqk+2B442qgiUQu7GyAm+mD1ick3vGrdlZgEEpr/U9EcVVGqXf3XN1EhlZa/vYGgO2opkKedFgbN53Hdd+xQ=='
));

$server_output = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_errno($curl);
print("CURL error: ");
print($err);
print($server_output);
```

Comment: It helps if you show the actual error

Comment: its a "failed sending network data"

Comment: remove your encoding and try sending.

Comment: @jgetner removed the encoding altogether, still gives the same error

Comment: Where is your curl_init() ?

Comment: @jgetner updated post to show it

Comment: Change curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); to curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 2); also remove the "\r\n" from "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",

Comment: @jgetner still gives the same error :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824108/how-can-i-use-the-new-spotify-api-using-php-curl

Comment: @jgetner that's similar but they're using client credentials instead of a refresh token. Also I tried deleting the \r\n from the first header and the error changed to 0 server_error. Tried changing one of the headers from Basic to Bearer as well and that didn't change anything.

Comment: @jgetner Wait that post actually solved what I was trying to do! Not in the same way but it works. Thanks you!